# Basic JavaScript, why is this function not passing the parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn JavaScript coming from C#. I wrote this simple code but for some reason, the parameter is not being passed to the setTimeout function.

```
function displayName(name) {
    console.log(`Name is ${ name }`);
}

function login(name) {
    // The argument 'name' is not being passed from the login function to the setTimeout !!
    setTimeout(name =>{
        displayName(name)
    }, 2000);
}

login("Satoshi")
```

I expect the output to be: `Name is Satoshi`
Instead I get: `Name is undefined`

Where am I going wrong? There's clearly something I am not understanding about JavaScript parameters and scope.

Comment: You never call `displayName()`.  You're calling `insert()`, but that doesn't exist.

Comment: The setTimeout is not going to pass `name` into the function when it is called.....`setTimeout(() =>{
        displayName(name)
    }, 2000);`

Comment: `name => ` declares a new function with an input parameter of `name` so that supersedes the `name` in `login(name)`

Comment: Also, `name => {insert(name)}` is equivalent to `function(name){ insert(name); }`.  Passing this function to `setTimeout()` doesn't work as `setTimeout()` doesn't pass its function any parameters.

Comment: @RocketHazmat `setTimeout` takes additional optional arguments which it can pass to the callback.  See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).  None of those optional arguments were supplied here, though.

Comment: @RocketHazmat My mistake. I edited it.

Comment: Thank you I think I get it now. Something to do with shadowing in Javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The argument 'name' is not being passed from the login function to the setTimeout !!

That's because you're *shadowing* the `login` `name` parameter with the parameter to your arrow function. A parameter name in a function parameter list is similar to a variable declaration within the function body, so your original code has an outer `name` (in `login`) and a separate inner one (in the arrow function). The innermost one is the one that gets used when you use the name of the parameter (or variable).

Replace `name` with `()` in the arrow function so it doesn't declare its own `name` parameter; then it will close over the `name` parameter in `login`:

```
function login(name) {
    setTimeout(() =>{
// −−−−−−−−−−−−^^
        displayName(name);
    }, 2000);
}
```

By default, `setTimeout` on browsers doesn't call the function you give it with any arguments, so the `name` parameter in the arrow function in your original code would always have the value `undefined`.

In some situations you may want `setTimeout` to pass an argument or arguments to the timer callback when calling it, which you do by passing those after the timeout interval, like this:

```
function login(name) {
    setTimeout(innerName =>{
//             ^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−− the arrow function's parameter
        displayName(innerName);
//                  ^^^^^^^^^−−− using the arrow function's parameter's value
    }, 2000, name);
//           ^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− `login`'s `name`
}
```

But there's no need for that in your example.

Comment: This worked. I'm going to have to look into shadowing. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation